# Android : How to provide auto logout at a specific time everyday with backup

Tags: android, backup, logout

My application has a login facility with account manager and it stores the account with oauth token after authentication.I need to logout this user automatically at 11:59:59 if the app is idle at that time on each day after backup the database data to application internal storage and need to clear the original database contents.If the user is working on the app at that time,then logout the user after 5 minute of inactivity.Also when the user comes after this auto logout the username should be shown in the login activity by default.How can i do that??Below is my code.

AccountAuthenticator.java:

```
        public class AccountAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
        private final Context context;
        private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

        public AccountAuthenticator(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse accountAuthenticatorResponse, String accountType,
                                 String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
            System.out.println("SaveItAuthenticator addAccount....");
            final Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_IS_ADDING_ACCOUNT, true);
            intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, accountAuthenticatorResponse);

            System.out.println("SaveItAuthenticator addAccount mid");
            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            if (options != null) {
                bundle.putAll(options);
            }
            bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
            System.out.println("SaveItAuthenticator addAccount end");
            return bundle;
        }

      /*  @Override
        public Bundle getAccountRemovalAllowed(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account) throws NetworkErrorException {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            boolean allowed = true;
            bundle.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, allowed);
            return bundle;
        }   */

        @Override
        public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse accountAuthenticatorResponse, Account account,
                                   String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
            System.out.println("SaveItAuthenticator getAuthToken....");
            if (!authTokenType.equals(AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY) &&
                    !authTokenType.equals(AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS)) {
                final Bundle result = new Bundle();
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, "Invalid authTokenType");
                return result;
            }

            final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context.getApplicationContext());

            String authToken = manager.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);

            Log.d("SaveItAndroidOauth", TAG + " > peekAuthToken returned - " + authToken);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
                System.out.println("***************   if  TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)  ******************");
                final String password = manager.getPassword(account);
                System.out.println("***************   password  ****************** "+password);
                final String refreshToken = manager.getUserData(account, LoginActivity.KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN);
                if (password != null) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Discounty > re-authenticating with refresh token "+refreshToken);
                        AccessToken accessToken = discountyService.getAccessToken(DiscountyService.ACCESS_GRANT_TYPE,
                                username, password).toBlocking().first();
                        authToken = accessToken.getValue();
                        RefreshToken tokenRef = accessToken.getRefreshToken();
                        String refreshtoken = tokenRef.getValue();
                    //    manager.setPassword(account,"password");
                        manager.setUserData(account, LoginActivity.KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshtoken);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
                final Bundle result = new Bundle();
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
                return result;
            }
            // If we get here, then we couldn't access the user's password - so we
            // need to re-prompt them for their credentials. We do that by creating
            // an intent to display our AuthenticatorActivity.
            final Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, accountAuthenticatorResponse);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
            return bundle;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
            if (AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS.equals(authTokenType)) {
                return AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS_LABEL;
            } else if (AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY.equals(authTokenType)) {
                return AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY_LABEL;
            } else {
                return authTokenType + " (Label)";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse accountAuthenticatorResponse, Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, false);
            return result;
        }

    }
```

LoginActivity.java :

```
        public class LoginActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {

        public final static String ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE = "ACCOUNT_TYPE";

        public final static String ARG_AUTH_TYPE = "AUTH_TYPE";

        public final static String ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME = "ACCOUNT_NAME";

        public final static String ARG_IS_ADDING_ACCOUNT = "AS_ADDING_ACCOUNT";

        public final static String KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE = "ERR_MSG";

        public static final String PARAM_USER_PASS = "USER_PASS";

        public static final String KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN = "REFRESH_TOKEN";
        /**
         * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
         */
        private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;
        /**
         * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
         * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
         */
        private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
                "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world",
                "yakovenko.denis.a@gmail.com:password", "a@:aaaaa"
        };

        private final int REQ_SIGNUP = 1;

        private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        private AccountManager accountManager;
        // 60 seconds (1 minute) * 180 = 3 hours
        public static final int SYNC_INTERVAL = 60;
        public static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME = SYNC_INTERVAL / 3;

        private String authTokenType;
        private EditText edtUserName,edtPassword;
        View mProgressView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            System.out.println("Login Activity starts....");

            accountManager = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());

            String accountName = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            authTokenType = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_AUTH_TYPE);

            edtUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUserName);
            edtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

            if (authTokenType != null) {
                authTokenType = AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS;
            }

            if (accountName != null) {
                edtUserName.setText(accountName);
            }

            findViewById(R.id.submit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    submit();
                }
            });
            findViewById(R.id.signUp).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Since there can only be one AuthenticatorActivity, we call the sign up activity, get his results,
                    // and return them in setAccountAuthenticatorResult(). See finishLogin().
                    Intent signup = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignUpActivity.class);
                    signup.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());
                    startActivityForResult(signup, REQ_SIGNUP);
                }
            });
        }

        public void submit() {
            final String userName = edtUserName.getText().toString();
            final String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();

            final String accountType = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

            new AsyncTask<String, Void, Intent>() {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
            //        showProgress(true);
                }

                @Override
                protected Intent doInBackground(String... params) {

                    Log.d("Discounty", TAG + " > Started authenticating"); // 1
                    String authtoken, refreshtoken;
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();

                    try {
    //                    if (NetworkHelper.isInternetAvailable(getBaseContext())) {
                        AccessToken accessToken = discountyService.getAccessToken(DiscountyService.ACCESS_GRANT_TYPE,
                                username, password).toBlocking().first();
                        authtoken = accessToken.getValue();
                        RefreshToken tokenRef = accessToken.getRefreshToken();
                        refreshtoken = tokenRef.getValue();
                        System.out.println("refreshtoken to store is "+refreshtoken);
                        data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, userName);
                        data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
                        data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authtoken);
                        data.putString(PARAM_USER_PASS, "password");//password
                        data.putString(KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshtoken);
    //                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        data.putString(KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, e.getMessage());
                    }

                    final Intent result = new Intent();
                    result.putExtras(data);
                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent) {
            //        showProgress(false);
                    if (intent.hasExtra(KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), intent.getStringExtra(KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Now finish login");  // 3
                        finishLogin(intent);
                    }
                }
            }.execute();
        }

        private void finishLogin(Intent intent) {
            String accountName = intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            String accountPassword = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_USER_PASS);

            final Account account = new Account(accountName, intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE));

            if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ARG_IS_ADDING_ACCOUNT, false)) {
                String authtoken = intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                String authtokenType = authTokenType;
                String refreshToken = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN);
                Bundle userData = new Bundle();
                userData.putString(KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken);
                accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, accountPassword, userData);
                accountManager.setAuthToken(account, authtokenType, authtoken);
                accountManager.setUserData(account,KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN,refreshToken);

                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            } else {
                System.out.println("condition else getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ARG_IS_ADDING_ACCOUNT, false)");
                accountManager.setPassword(account, accountPassword);
            }
            setAccountAuthenticatorResult(intent.getExtras());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }

    }
```

MainActivity.java :

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String STATE_DIALOG = "state_dialog";

        private static final String STATE_INVALIDATE = "state_invalidate";

        private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

        private AccountManager accountManager;

        private AlertDialog alertDialog;

        private boolean invalidate;

        Account mAccount;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

            if (accountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE).length == 0) {
                addNewAccount(accountManager);
            } else {
                Account[] accountList = accountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                mAccount = accountList[0];
                System.out.println("There is an account...."+mAccount);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

        }


        private void addNewAccount(AccountManager manager) {

        final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture = manager.addAccount(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, null, null, this,
                new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture) {
                        System.out.println("AccountManagerFuture starts running...."); // 6
                        try {
                            Bundle bnd = accountManagerFuture.getResult();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    }
                    }, null);
        }

        private void performLogout() {
            try {
                Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                if (accounts.length != 0) {
                    ContentResolver.cancelSync(accounts[0],"com.fortune.saveitandroidoauth");
                    final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0], AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, null, this, null,null);

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Bundle bnd = future.getResult();

                                final String authtoken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                                System.out.println("User is going to logout "+authtoken);
                                serverAuthenticateService.logOut(authtoken);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();

                    Log.d("ACCOUNT", accounts[0].toString());
                    Log.d("ACCOUNT TOKEN TYPE", accounts[0].type);
                    Log.d("ACCOUNT TOKEN NAME", accounts[0].name);//accountManagerFuture

                    accountManager.clearPassword(accounts[0]);
            //        accountManager.setUserData(accounts[0],LoginActivity.KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN, null);
                    String accessToken = accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0], AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, null, true,
                            new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                                @Override
                                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture) {
                                    System.out.println("invalidate thread running....");

                                    try {
                                        System.out.println("invalidateAuthToken...."+accountManagerFuture.getResult().toString());
                                        Log.d("invalidateAuthToken", accountManagerFuture.getResult().toString());
                                    } catch (android.accounts.OperationCanceledException | AuthenticatorException | IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, null).toString();

                    accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE,accessToken);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) { // use deprecated method
                        System.out.println("removeAccount .... SDK_INT < 22 ");
                        accountManager.removeAccount(accounts[0], null, null);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("removeAccountExplicitly .... SDK_INT >= 22 ");
                        accountManager.removeAccountExplicitly(accounts[0]);
                    }
                    addNewAccount(accountManager);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_sync:
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_logout:
                    performLogout();
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

DBHelper.java :

```
            public class DBHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

            private Context context;
            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.db";
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
            private Dao<AccountingPeriod,Integer> accPerDao=null;


            public DBHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                this.context=context;
            }
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
                try{
                    Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),"onCreate");
                    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, AccountingPeriod.class);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Unable to create datbases", ex);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVer, int newVer) {
                try{
                    Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),"onUpgrade");
                    TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, AccountingPeriod.class, true);
                    onCreate(sqliteDatabase, connectionSource);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't drop databases", ex);
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }

            public Dao<AccountingPeriod, Integer> getAccPerDao() throws SQLException {
                if (accPerDao == null) {
                    accPerDao = getDao(AccountingPeriod.class);
                }
                return accPerDao;
            }

            @Override
            public void close() {
                super.close();
            }
            public void deleteAll() {
                try{
                    TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, AccountingPeriod.class, true);
                    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = null;
                    onCreate(sqliteDatabase, connectionSource);
                }catch(Exception ew){

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can do using sharedpprefernce and Alram Manager....... At Fix Alram Remove the shardprefernce data (Logout and refresh)

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini How its been possible.Please show me...